# Resize срабатывает не на всех изображениях

Tags: php, resize

Недавно заметил один очень странный баг. Resize срабатывает не на всех изображениях которые я добавляю. А именно не срабатывает если фото добавлено с андроида. И что самое интересное, ресайз срабатывает выборочно. Покажу на примере. Есть скрипт уменьшения изображений (создание превью):

```
function resize ($filename, $size)
{
$pref = 'mini_';
$img = strtolower(strrchr(basename($filename), "."));
$imgname = basename($filename);
$formats = array('.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.bmp');
if (in_array($img, $formats))
{
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_height = $height * $size;
$new_width = $new_height / $width;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $new_width);
switch ($img)
{
case '.jpg': $source = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); break;
case '.gif': $source = @imagecreatefromgif($filename); break;
case '.png': $source = @imagecreatefrompng($filename); break;
case '.bmp': $source = @imagecreatefromwbmp($filename); break;
}
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size, $new_width, $width, $height);
switch ($img)
{
case '.jpg': imagejpeg($thumb, $pref.$imgname); break;
case '.gif': imagegif($thumb, $pref.$imgname); break;
case '.png': imagepng($thumb, $pref.$imgname); break;
case '.bmp': imagewbmp($thumb, $pref.$imgname); break;
}
}
else return 'Error';
@imagedestroy($thumb);
@imagedestroy($source);
return $imgname;
}
```

Одни изображения обрабатывает и сохраняет превью, а другие не хочет. И такая проблема возникает лишь тогда, если изображения добавлены с Android устройства. Для теста выгрузил два одинаковых изображения, одно с телефона, второе с компьютера. То что с компьютера - скрипт уменьшил и создал копию, а вот то что с телефона - не обработалось вообще.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за странный баг и можно ли его обойти?

Ошибки интерпретатора:

```
Warning: Division by zero in /t.php on line 17

Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in /t.php on line 18

Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /t.php on line 26

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /t.php on line 29
```

Comment: На нуль делить нельзя. Это вам строчка 17 говорит. Грех такое со школы не запомнить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит из-за некорректной работы `getimagesize()`. В определенных случаях она возвращает вместо размера ноли. Можно использовать её аналоги.

Так же некоторые браузеры могут не посылать название файла вместе с содержимым. При определении типа файла опираться на расширение файла не стоит, лучше опираться на mime-тип содержимого файла. Он почти всегда верный.

```
<?php
// Retrieve JPEG width and height without downloading/reading entire image.
function getjpegsize($img_loc) {
    $handle = fopen($img_loc, "rb") or die("Invalid file stream.");
    $new_block = NULL;
    if(!feof($handle)) {
        $new_block = fread($handle, 32);
        $i = 0;
        if($new_block[$i]=="\xFF" && $new_block[$i+1]=="\xD8" && $new_block[$i+2]=="\xFF" && $new_block[$i+3]=="\xE0") {
            $i += 4;
            if($new_block[$i+2]=="\x4A" && $new_block[$i+3]=="\x46" && $new_block[$i+4]=="\x49" && $new_block[$i+5]=="\x46" && $new_block[$i+6]=="\x00") {
                // Read block size and skip ahead to begin cycling through blocks in search of SOF marker
                $block_size = unpack("H*", $new_block[$i] . $new_block[$i+1]);
                $block_size = hexdec($block_size[1]);
                while(!feof($handle)) {
                    $i += $block_size;
                    $new_block .= fread($handle, $block_size);
                    if($new_block[$i]=="\xFF") {
                        // New block detected, check for SOF marker
                        $sof_marker = array("\xC0", "\xC1", "\xC2", "\xC3", "\xC5", "\xC6", "\xC7", "\xC8", "\xC9", "\xCA", "\xCB", "\xCD", "\xCE", "\xCF");
                        if(in_array($new_block[$i+1], $sof_marker)) {
                            // SOF marker detected. Width and height information is contained in bytes 4-7 after this byte.
                            $size_data = $new_block[$i+2] . $new_block[$i+3] . $new_block[$i+4] . $new_block[$i+5] . $new_block[$i+6] . $new_block[$i+7] . $new_block[$i+8];
                            $unpacked = unpack("H*", $size_data);
                            $unpacked = $unpacked[1];
                            $height = hexdec($unpacked[6] . $unpacked[7] . $unpacked[8] . $unpacked[9]);
                            $width = hexdec($unpacked[10] . $unpacked[11] . $unpacked[12] . $unpacked[13]);
                            return array($width, $height);
                        } else {
                            // Skip block marker and read block size
                            $i += 2;
                            $block_size = unpack("H*", $new_block[$i] . $new_block[$i+1]);
                            $block_size = hexdec($block_size[1]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// Retrieve PNG width and height without downloading/reading entire image.
function getpngsize( $img_loc ) {
    $handle = fopen( $img_loc, "rb" ) or die( "Invalid file stream." );

    if ( ! feof( $handle ) ) {
        $new_block = fread( $handle, 24 );
        if ( $new_block[0] == "\x89" &&
            $new_block[1] == "\x50" &&
            $new_block[2] == "\x4E" &&
            $new_block[3] == "\x47" &&
            $new_block[4] == "\x0D" &&
            $new_block[5] == "\x0A" &&
            $new_block[6] == "\x1A" &&
            $new_block[7] == "\x0A" ) {
                if ( $new_block[12] . $new_block[13] . $new_block[14] . $new_block[15] === "\x49\x48\x44\x52" ) {
                    $width  = unpack( 'H*', $new_block[16] . $new_block[17] . $new_block[18] . $new_block[19] );
                    $width  = hexdec( $width[1] );
                    $height = unpack( 'H*', $new_block[20] . $new_block[21] . $new_block[22] . $new_block[23] );
                    $height  = hexdec( $height[1] );

                    return array( $width, $height );
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}
?>
```

Если PHP установлен с поддержкой ImageMagick, можно использовать такой код для качественных превьюшек:

```
<?php

$thumb = new Imagick('myimage.jpg');

$thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.gif');

$thumb->destroy();

?>
```

Работает медленно, но качество превьюшки такое же, как при ресайзе используя Photoshop.

PS. автор кода не я, используйте на свой страх и риск.

Comment: Понял. Благодарю, буду пробовать.